# How to unlock bootloader on nexus from bootloader/PC command line

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, nexus-5x, nexus

I have a nexus 5X phone, which needs a factory reset to fix it's infinite boot loop. The problem is that the bootloader says `DEVICE STATE - locked`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I can't boot into android, and oem and the bootloader are locked out.

Comment: ah ok, i understand. so you can not unlock from fastboot because oem unlocking is not allowed in developer settings. but did you try factory reset from recovery mode?

Comment: Tried, but can't even access recovery mode. That too gives infinite  boot loop. Its completely locked into fastboot. I'm looking for a way around that isn't a new phone.

Comment: Maybe flashing a new system with a factory signed .img will work.  https://developers.google.com/android/images

Comment: @BoLawson can signed img flashed from fastboot without unlocking, or you mean flashing with QFIL or QPST?

Comment: Google Nexus is in real LG brand!? Here someone claimed to use LGUP Tool https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63969457&postcount=10

Comment: @alecxs yes a factory signed .img can be flashed from a locked bootloader especially from a developmental device such as a Nexus. Another possible option, there is the Nexus root toolkit from Wugfresh.

Comment: @BoLawson so step 4. from the tutorial you posted can just be skipped?

Comment: @alecxs should be at least it was like that in the past.I believe that is why it states `if necessary`. However it also I states if "updated".

Comment: Nexus root toolkit looks promising, but i am afraid it is just a gui for fastboot/adb commands

Comment: Tried all of these, and contacted LG and google. They both say the phone is probably toast, even in the unlikely event I manage to flash a new img.